# nestedSortables snap option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

This question is related to the jQuery plugin, nestedSortables - [Plugin Site](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

Is it possible to incorporate the jQueryUI draggables 'Snap' option within nestedSortables?

The plugin uses sortables and not draggables so doesn't currently support the 'snap' option.

I've also posted this on the plugin support forum, but responses don't seem to happen often so thought I would post here too.

Thanks!

Adam